# ibm watson voice stream does not output a text transcript

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

this community has been helpful so far in my development of this app. anyways I am able to connect now to ibm watson servers but I am unsure if I am able to output a transcript of my voice.

I dunno what is wrong nor what I need to modify in order for me to be able to set the transcript to a TextView

MainActivity.java

```
    /*
 * Copyright 2017 IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on
 * an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 */
package com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneHelper;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneInputStream;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.StreamPlayer;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.utils.ContentType;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.camera.CameraHelper;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.camera.GalleryHelper;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.LanguageTranslator;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.TranslateOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.model.TranslationResult;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v3.util.Language;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.RecognizeOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechRecognitionResults;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.BaseRecognizeCallback;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.TextToSpeech;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.text_to_speech.v1.model.SynthesizeOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

  private EditText input;
  private ImageButton mic;
  private Button translate;
  private ImageButton play;
  private TextView translatedText;
  private ImageView loadedImage;

  private SpeechToText speechService;
  private TextToSpeech textService;
  private LanguageTranslator translationService;
  private String selectedTargetLanguage = Language.SPANISH;

  private StreamPlayer player = new StreamPlayer();

  private CameraHelper cameraHelper;
  private GalleryHelper galleryHelper;
  private MicrophoneHelper microphoneHelper;

  private MicrophoneInputStream capture;
  private boolean listening = false;

  /**
   * On create.
   *
   * @param savedInstanceState the saved instance state
   */
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cameraHelper = new CameraHelper(this);
    galleryHelper = new GalleryHelper(this);
    microphoneHelper = new MicrophoneHelper(this);

    speechService = initSpeechToTextService();


    RadioGroup targetLanguage = findViewById(R.id.target_language);
    input = findViewById(R.id.input);
    mic = findViewById(R.id.mic);
    translate = findViewById(R.id.translate);
    play = findViewById(R.id.play);
    translatedText = findViewById(R.id.translated_text);
    Button gallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery_button);
    Button camera = findViewById(R.id.camera_button);


    targetLanguage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
          case R.id.spanish:
            selectedTargetLanguage = Language.SPANISH;
            break;
          case R.id.french:
            selectedTargetLanguage = Language.FRENCH;
            break;
          case R.id.italian:
            selectedTargetLanguage = Language.ITALIAN;
            break;
        }
      }
    });

    input.addTextChangedListener(new EmptyTextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void onEmpty(boolean empty) {
        if (empty) {
          translate.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
          translate.setEnabled(true);
        }
      }
    });

    mic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!listening) {
          // Update the icon background
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
          });
          capture = microphoneHelper.getInputStream(true);
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {
                speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(getRecognizeOptions(capture),
                    new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                showError(e);
              }
            }
          }).start();

          listening = true;
        } else {
          // Update the icon background
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
          });
          microphoneHelper.closeInputStream();
          listening = false;
        }
      }
    });

   /* translate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        new TranslationTask().execute(input.getText().toString());
      }
    });

    translatedText.addTextChangedListener(new EmptyTextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void onEmpty(boolean empty) {
        if (empty) {
          play.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
          play.setEnabled(true);
        }
      }
    });

    play.setEnabled(false);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        new SynthesisTask().execute(translatedText.getText().toString());
      }
    });*/

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        galleryHelper.dispatchGalleryIntent();
      }
    });

    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        cameraHelper.dispatchTakePictureIntent();
      }
    });
  }


  private void showTranslation(final String translation) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        translatedText.setText(translation);
      }
    });
  }

  private void showError(final Exception e) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Update the icon background
        mic.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
      }
    });
  }

  private void showMicText(final String text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        input.setText(text);
      }
    });
  }

  private void enableMicButton() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        mic.setEnabled(true);
      }
    });
  }

  private SpeechToText initSpeechToTextService() {
    IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
            .apiKey("{"+getString(R.string.speech_text_iam_apikey)+"}")
            .build();
    SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText(options);
    service.setEndPoint(getString(R.string.speech_text_url));
    return service;

  }



  private RecognizeOptions getRecognizeOptions(InputStream captureStream) {
    return new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
            .audio(captureStream)

            .contentType(ContentType.OPUS.toString())
            .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
            .interimResults(true)
            .inactivityTimeout(2000)
            .build();
  }

  private abstract class EmptyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    // assumes text is initially empty
    private boolean isEmpty = true;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if (s.length() == 0) {
        isEmpty = true;
        onEmpty(true);
      } else if (isEmpty) {
        isEmpty = false;
        onEmpty(false);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public abstract void onEmpty(boolean empty);
  }

  private class MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate extends BaseRecognizeCallback {
    @Override
    public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
      System.out.println(speechResults);
      if (speechResults.getResults() != null && !speechResults.getResults().isEmpty()) {
        String text = speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript();
        showMicText(text);
      }
    }


    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
      try {
        // This is critical to avoid hangs
        // (see https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/issues/59)
        capture.close();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      showError(e);
      enableMicButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
      enableMicButton();
    }
  }
/*
  private class TranslationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      TranslateOptions translateOptions = new TranslateOptions.Builder()
              .addText(params[0])
              .source(Language.ENGLISH)
              .target(selectedTargetLanguage)
              .build();
      TranslationResult result = translationService.translate(translateOptions).execute();
      String firstTranslation = result.getTranslations().get(0).getTranslationOutput();
      showTranslation(firstTranslation);
      return "Did translate";
    }
  }

  private class SynthesisTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      SynthesizeOptions synthesizeOptions = new SynthesizeOptions.Builder()
              .text(params[0])
              .voice(SynthesizeOptions.Voice.EN_US_LISAVOICE)
              .accept(SynthesizeOptions.Accept.AUDIO_WAV)
              .build();
      player.playStream(textService.synthesize(synthesizeOptions).execute());
      return "Did synthesize";
    }
  }*/

  /**
   * On request permissions result.
   *
   * @param requestCode the request code
   * @param permissions the permissions
   * @param grantResults the grant results
   */
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                         String[] permissions,
                                         int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case CameraHelper.REQUEST_PERMISSION: {
        // permission granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          cameraHelper.dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
      }
      case MicrophoneHelper.REQUEST_PERMISSION: {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Permission to record audio denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * On activity result.
   *
   * @param requestCode the request code
   * @param resultCode the result code
   * @param data the data
   */
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CameraHelper.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      loadedImage.setImageBitmap(cameraHelper.getBitmap(resultCode));
    }

    if (requestCode == GalleryHelper.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      loadedImage.setImageBitmap(galleryHelper.getBitmap(resultCode, data));
    }
  }
}
```

This is what logcat says

```
2019-02-06 16:32:36.942 7926-7926/? I/d.myapplicatio: Not late-enabling -

Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-02-06 16:32:37.042 7926-7926/? W/d.myapplicatio: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-02-06 16:32:37.168 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/d.myapplicatio: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-02-06 16:32:37.557 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-02-06 16:32:37.559 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/chatty: uid=10088(com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication) identical 9 lines
2019-02-06 16:32:37.559 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-02-06 16:32:37.622 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2019-02-06 16:32:37.622 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/MultiDex: install
2019-02-06 16:32:37.622 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2019-02-06 16:32:37.650 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-02-06 16:32:37.959 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-06 16:32:37.963 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-06 16:32:38.284 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/CredentialUtils: JNDI string lookups is not available.
2019-02-06 16:32:38.286 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/CredentialUtils: JNDI string lookups is not available.
2019-02-06 16:32:38.379 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-02-06 16:32:38.393 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-06 16:32:38.393 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-06 16:32:38.393 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-06 16:32:38.428 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-02-06 16:32:38.502 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-06 16:32:38.502 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-06 16:32:38.502 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-02-06 16:32:38.502 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-02-06 16:32:38.503 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-02-06 16:32:38.503 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-02-06 16:32:38.521 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe6441b20: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-02-06 16:32:38.552 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe6441b20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe6431bd0)
2019-02-06 16:32:38.657 7926-7952/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe6441b20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe6431bd0)
2019-02-06 16:32:38.804 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication W/d.myapplicatio: JNI critical lock held for 16.902ms on Thread[1,tid=7926,Runnable,Thread*=0xe64d9000,peer=0x744aeee0,"main"]
2019-02-06 16:32:38.812 7926-7926/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 5464 bytes, containing 1 windows, 18 views
2019-02-06 16:35:03.857 7926-7955/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication E/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneInputStream: Pipe closed
2019-02-06 16:35:03.857 7926-7955/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication E/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneInputStream: Pipe closed
```

I am unsure when it comes to wireshark if I am really able to transmit data to the ibm watson server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and it was all the fault of faulty docu on the tutorial part of ibm watson.

instead of

```
 private SpeechToText initSpeechToTextService() {
IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
        .apiKey("{"+getString(R.string.speech_text_iam_apikey)+"}")
        .build();
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText(options);
service.setEndPoint(getString(R.string.speech_text_url));
return service;


}
```

Remove the {} on  `.apiKey("{"+getString(R.string.speech_text_iam_apikey)+"}")` and use it directly

```
  private SpeechToText initSpeechToTextService() {
IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
        .apiKey(getString(R.string.speech_text_iam_apikey))
        .build();
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText(options);
service.setEndPoint(getString(R.string.speech_text_url));
return service;



}
```

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find that error?

Comment: it was my failure to understand that you do not have to add {} inside the string code but instead add api code directly

Comment: Thanks, this works. For those struggling, remember to add `import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamOptions;` in as well.